# Why is Helvetica only used sometimes, Arial otherwise?

Tags: discussion, fonts

Helvetica (Neue) is used for `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `input`, `select`, `button`, and a few other specific elements. Yet for the main font declaration on `body`, Helvetica is nowhere to be found, only its [impostor](http://www.ms-studio.com/articles.html), Arial. Since Helvetica is already being used for parts of the site's typography, I don't see why it shouldn't be for all of it.

The layout is not adversely affected by putting Helvetica in front of Arial, as can be evidenced below in the difference between [Arial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLx8Q.png) & [Helvetica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFVgH.png) (addition is purple, subtraction green).

[image: Arial/Helvetica difference]

Comment: I would +1 again for correctly spelling the word "impostor".

Comment: @BoltClock I've just checked in the Merriam-Webster dictionary and actually both *impostor* and *imposter* are valid. Besides that, with modern spell checkers there's no excuse for using wrong spelling.

Comment: I was looking at the two images thinking *Well I kind of prefer the second one, even though it's surely Arial - but... that's borderline blasphemy!* Turns out it was Helvetica. I'm kind of relieved now. :)

Comment: Helvetica or death!

Comment: As an aside: simply adding Helvetica to `font-family` might need [some alignment tweak for the close links in dialogs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119558/why-cant-stack-overflow-vertically-center-the-x-in-its-close-boxes). (Or the dialogs close links could stick to Arial.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have all been long reverted by now.

I am not a fan of Helv (Neue) on the trilogy, to put it mildly.

Comment: Are there any special reasons?

Comment: Arial is a very, very well understood font at this point. It ain't broke.

Comment: The cat ate the font? ;)

Comment: Excuse me, but how do I have to understand the "understood" in this sentence? Do you mean it is a well known/accepted font?