# Why can't Stack Overflow vertically center the X in its close boxes?

Tags: support, design, notification-bar

When I visit Stack Overflow and I've got the orange notification bar at the top of the page, there's a little "X" to close the bar. However, that X is not centered vertically within its box. This has bugged me for a long time and I figured it was a temporary thing. But it's never been fixed. Now I'm chalking it up to sloppiness.

As seen in Safari on Lion:

[image: X]

I've deleted Arial from my system (it's ugly).

Comment: I have no issue with the placement of the box itself, just the X inside the box.

Comment: Hmm, I [don't seem to have that problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/smwDK.png) in Chrome 18 / Windows 7.

Comment: @jbrennan, sorry, didn't see that at first. The problem won't be easy to reproduce, though...

Comment: I don't see it out of line, either

Comment: Fair enough. But I see it in Safari. So it's a bug.

Comment: @jbrennan They are not saying it is not a bug; they are reporting they don't have the issue, which could help the developers to find what is wrong. (At least, knowing that some browsers render the page differently can help to make the page more similar though different browsers.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Oh yeah, I'm aware :) I realize the importance of narrowing it down. Some of the earlier comments mistakenly thought I meant something else, which they were saying isn't a bug. But this one is, in Safari.

Comment: No repro for me on Linux with the current repo version of Chromium.  @FrédéricHamidi To try, find your JS console and input this: `StackExchange.notify.show("You have gained the superpower!","1")`

Comment: _A bug? Really?!_ It's a couple pixels out, and it's purely design - the button works as intended. _Ugly?_ Maybe. _Bug?_ Hardly.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment It's still a bug. It's crappy user experience. It's not that it's *terrible* but it detracts from SO. It makes it feel more amateurish. If my software isn't polished, I consider it needs fixing.

Comment: @jbrennan Sometimes my car needs fixing, doesn't mean is has a _'bug'_.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Unless SO breaks down with regular use, I'd say this is a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment @ jbrennan Hey, let's get into an argument about the definition of a bug! It'll be so fun!  In [my bug categorization process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426319/should-you-charge-a-customer-for-bug-fixes/426509#426509), this would be referred to as a "superficial bug".  Some people refer to similar problems as "issues" rather than bugs, although they all still go into the same "issue tracking" database.  So, what is your terminology, and do you actually track such issues in a different database/spreadsheet/piece of paper than issues you think of as "bugs"?

Comment: Alternately, on could define "bug" as "aspect of the system as realized does not match the requirements as specified." If it was intended to be centered, and it's not, then it's a bug - there's a mismatch between reality and intention.  If it's not in the requirements, then it might be a UI nitpick, but it isn't necessarily a bug. In this case we don't necessarily know if the X is supposed to be vertically centered or not in the stack exchange inc design specification, so we can't tell.  **There, now you have my definition, feel free to continue the argument after stating your definition.**

Comment: I realize this is `meta.stackoverflow.com` and all, but I think this is too meta. Call it a bug, call it an issue, it doesn't really matter and it's completely missing the point of why I posted this.

Comment: @jbrennan you deleted a core system font, what do you expect? You've made yourself an uber-edge case. You wouldn't take the spoiler off a car because it's ugly then complain the car takes off.

Comment: Misplacing an X is not a bug.  That was pretty funny though.

Comment: [Oh, Slidy...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/).

Comment: Guys, take this conversation to http://meta.meta.stackoverflow.com, eh? Off topic!

Answer (score 3):

On a stock install of Lion, I see a smaller font in Safari (though not perfectly aligned there either).

Any chance you're zoomed in, or have replaced some fonts? Or maybe your Apple's Arial has been replaced by a Microsoft version after installing Microsoft Office? (These fonts, incidentally, have [caused much bigger issues](https://superuser.com/questions/66295/arabic-in-powerpoint-on-mac/66305#66305).)

Actually, though the image is a bit a small to compare, it seems [you're using Helvetica](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/06/arial-versus-helvetica/)? That's odd, as that is not in the CSS, assuming it's Stack Overflow:

```
font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
```

[image]

To see what font you're using: copy the text, paste into TextEdit, and then click in the text to see the font in the font dropdown. Mine says Arial, Bold, 17:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've deleted Arial from my system (it's ugly). Must be what's causing this. But still... I'm inclined to say it should be fixed :).

Comment: Really, for `font-family`, one should always put `Helvetica, Arial, etc` in such cases. Mac and iOS users get the better typography, and everyone else still gets what they would have got anyway: Arial.

Comment: But as Helvetica needs a bit more space, it also needs some more  effort than just changing the `font-family`, like you've just proven yourself? Still you might want to vote for [Why is Helvetica only used sometimes, Arial otherwise?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112870/why-is-helvetica-only-used-sometimes-arial-otherwise) then.

Comment: isn't that the definition of fixing a bug? :) Fixing a bug involves some work!

Comment: I've seen the smiley, but on a serious note: then I don't think it's a bug, but merely a duplicate of the feature request I mentioned above.